# passing variable to docker command

Tags: docker, powershell

Running

```
docker run -t -i -w=[absolute_work_dir] [docker_image] [executable]
```

is fine. However when I set the workdir using variable in a PowerShell script (.ps1):

```
$WORKDIR = [absolute_work_dir]
docker run -t -i -w=$WORKDIR [docker_image] [executable]
```

it gave the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory '$WORKDIR' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
```

What is possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could assemble a string with your variable, then execute the string as a command.

```
$DOCKRUNSTR = "docker run -t -i -w=" + $WORKDIR + " [docker_image] [executable]"
& $DOCKRUNSTR
```

The `&` will tell powershell to run that string as a command.

Edit: Inside a .ps1 file try `Invoke-Expression` instead of `&`

Maybe there's a better powershell super user solution, but this seems like it could get the job done for you.

Comment: & $DOCKRUNSTR doesn't work

Comment: @kstn I tested only in the shell not in a .ps1 file. & does work in the shell. However, inside your .ps1 file try:

`Invoke-Expression $DOCKRUNSTR`

Comment: Another thing, if you are able to pass the path to the command succesfully, but it still thinks that the path is not absolute, it could be a docker problem. Check this issue if that occurs: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2204